# Tekton pipeline conditional run

Tags: pipeline, tekton

I have a pipeline with following tasks.

```
- name: A
     taskRef:
        name: buildah-secondary-tag-task       
      runAfter:
        -  maven-prepare-package
      when:
        - input: "$(params.type)"
          operator: in
          values: ["app"]
- name: B
      taskRef:
        name: buildah-secondary-tag-task       
      runAfter:
        -  maven-prepare-package
      when:
        - input: "$(params.courtType)"
          operator: in
          values: ["bapp"]

 - name: C 
      taskRef:
        name: buildah-secondary-tag-task
      runAfter:
        -  A
```

Task A and B are different depending on the params.type A or B is executed but Task C has to run after A or B has been exectued. How can I specify in the that condition in runAfter for task C

Comment: Could you create a Task D, that is similar to C but runAfter B?

Answer (score 0):

Using a single pipeline, you can not ensure task C would runAfter A and B, unless both A and B were executed, [see docs](https://tekton.dev/docs/pipelines/pipelines/#guard-task-execution-using-conditions) somewhat hinting that "when" condition evaluating to false would block execution for tasks that "runAfter" that conditional task.

What you could try is to add some "[finally](https://tekton.dev/docs/pipelines/pipelines/#adding-finally-to-the-pipeline)" block, that would either trigger another Pipeline, or include your task C.